# Ruby regex for parsing underscores as italic

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to add italics to text that matches a regular expression, but it's failing:

```
string = 'this should have _emphasis_ but this_one_should_not'
string.gsub!(%r{ (\*|_) (\S|\S.*?\S) \1 }x, %{<em>\\2</em>})
string.should == 'this should have <em>emphasis</em> but this_one_should_not'

# actual = 'this should have <em>emphasis</em> but this<em>one</em>should_not'
```

The one with italics in the middle is incorrectly being turned italic. I copied this code from somewhere else, but I need to adjust it so that it works for this use case.

Comment: Are you dealing with text containing Markdown formatting? If so, why not use a gem for converting it? It'll automatically add the formatting.

Comment: because I only need to support a small set of markdown (em, strong, links, etc) and I can't find any that allow me to pick and choose the elements that I want to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that works:

```
string = 'this should have _emphasis_ but this_one_should_not'
string.gsub!(%r{(^|\s)([*_])(.+?)\2(\s|$)}x, %{\\1<em>\\3</em>\\4})
string.should == 'this should have <em>emphasis</em> but this_one_should_not'
```

And [here's a demo](http://codepad.org/szLL2eFU).

Comment: ...however, it is also wrapping strong tags: `**bold**` is becoming `<em>*strong*</em>`